# How to get Azure Cloud startup environment variables to persist

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-cloud-services

For Azure Cloud Services, when you define Startup Tasks in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file, you have the option of setting environment variables. It looks something like this:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="install.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="YourEnvironmentVariable" value="YourValue"/>
    </Environment>
  </Task>
</Startup>
```

That environment variable only seems to persist for the duration of the Task it's defined in (in this case, running install.cmd). If you RDP into your cloud instance and check the environment variables, you won't see it listed there. Is there a way to get that environment variable to persist?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear as if the Azure Cloud Framework gives you an easy way to do this, but it's possible. I persisted the Environment Variable by having install.cmd manually set it. In my case, `install.cmd` called a PowerShell script that did the following:

```
# Make the environment variables defined in ServiceDefinition.csdef persist
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("YourEnvironmentVariable", "$Env:YourEnvironmentVariable", "Machine")
```

You could accomplish this without using PowerShell. It would look something like this:

```
setx YourEnvironmentVariable "%YourEnvironmentVariable%" /M
```